# hardhat forked mainet, blocknumber not updated in loop

Tags: hardhat

Try to get an updated block number in this hardhat forked mainnet, but just receive the same block number within the while loop like below. The same code tested in mainnet is fine. what is missing in the hardhat forked mainnet?

latestBlock number is 15758880
latestBlock number is 15758880
latestBlock number is 15758880
latestBlock number is 15758880

```
main();

async function main() {
  let latestBlock = await ethers.provider.getBlock("latest");

  while (1 == 1) {
    latestBlock = await ethers.provider.getBlock("latest");
    console.log(`latestBlock number is ${latestBlock.number}`);
    await sleep(20000);
  }
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: What is the ganache command line used for the fork? It could be that it is waiting for you to send new transactions. Once a network is forked it stops getting new blocks from the original network.